# How do I create a new pandas column based on logic selected at run time by the user

Tags: python, pandas, dynamic

I want to be able to create a new column in a dataframe based on a user-selected formula. The answer is obvious when the formula selection is known prior to running, but I'm unsure how to proceed in the case where the formula is unknown until runtime.

The number of columns in the dataframe can vary, and the number of variables/operations per formula can vary as well, so a lambda function doesn't seem appropriate

---

Ex. `df` has integer values in column "A" and float values in column "B". there are 3 formulas,

- `1` - add the value in A to the value in B
- `2` - subtract the value in B from the square of the value in A
- `3` - add the value in A to the value in B

the user inputs `1`, `2` or `3` at runtime, and the corresponding formula is used to create column "C" with the appropriate values.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you not ask for a User Input in the middle of your program and create columns accordingly?

Comment: Can you explain why lambda function won't work. What do you mean by formula is unknown untill runtime.

Comment: at runtime, the user selects columns and operations to define formulas via a GUI. At various stages during runtime, the user can create new columns by selecting already stored formulas or define new ones. I've tried to distill a formula object (attributes include values, operations, etc.) but that route led to messy and ineffective code

Comment: @PavanKumar in the example provided, the formula being used to create column "C" is unknown until runtime because the user does not select from options 1, 2 and 3 until prompted at runtim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_formula(user_input):
  formula = None
  if user_input == 1:
    formula = lambda x: x['A'] + x['B']
  elif user_input == 2:
    formula = lambda x: x['A']**2 - x['B']
  elif user_input == 3:
    # Your conditions for user inputs 1 or 3 seem to be the same.
    formula = lambda x: x['A'] + x['B']
  else:
    # Error out
    pass
  return formula

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(5)), 'B': list(range(5))})

# Get user input (assumes it's an integer)
user_input = int(input('Enter formula #: '))
# Get formula based on input
fn = get_formula(user_input)
# Assign new column 'C' based on formula
df.assign(C=fn)

# Assuming user input is 1, this outputs:
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  4
3  3  3  6
4  4  4  8
```

You can use [DataFrame.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) together with a formula decided at run-time. This takes advantage of functions being objects in Python.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!